# QGIS convert long integers stored as string to integer

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I have long integers (11 characters) stored as text in a shapefile that I need to convert to integers, but when I attempt to convert them in the QGIS field calculator, I get the following error:

```
Eval Error:
Cannot convert '26001980100' to int
```

The value in the error code above is the value from the first row in the field. I though this might be due to a field width constraint in shapefiles for integer columns, so I then imported the shapefile into a spatialite database and tried again without success. In both cases I was trying to create a new field populated by the converted values. How can I convert this field to integer?

The problem appears to goes deeper: after creating a new field and populating it with the integer values via the spatialite command line tool, QGIS does not then "see" the new field in the updated table. Am I out of luck with long integers in QGIS?

QGIS 2.12.3

Edit: I'm not sure whether this is a duplicate because the error appears specific to cases of converting strings having a length greater than 10 to integer. I tried the answer supplied [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75021/convert-string-to-integer-in-qgis-tables) to convert to integer without luck. However, I was able to use that answer to convert the field to REAL, which is adequate for my purposes. The field in question is a foreign key, and the tables containing the primary key all store the values as INT, so I wanted to be consistent, but I can still join INT to REAL.

Answer (score 2):

In spatialite you should be able to do a cast. Assuming a table "numbers" with one TEXT column, "number_str" (that represents integers) and a second column "number_ints" that was defined as INTEGER, then

```
UPDATE numbers SET number_ints=(CAST(number_str AS INTEGER));
```

More details on the sqlite concept of "affinity" and the CAST function are [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr)

Regarding your "disappearing" column, this may be the same bug reported in the QGIS [issue tracker](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13504). Something weird with creating columns in a spatialite DB, not through the QGIS interface, but it will get solved eventually.
[Here's](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/spatialite-users/qgis$20disappearing$20column/spatialite-users/uGDZr1TCTn8/YrBFTv2PBQAJ) the post on the spatialite-user's maillist explaining the workaround. It involves running

```
SELECT InvalidateLayerStatistics();
SELECT UpdateLayerStatistics();
```

Comment: thanks, but I tried to say that I had already been able to cast the string field as integer in a new field via spatialite. The problem then was that I couldn't see it in QGIS in the attribute table. Casting as REAL took care of the issue, but bothers me a bit because it is inconsistent with my other data, i.e., the field is a foreign key and the primary keys I want to join to are stored as INT.

Comment: The workaround on the spatialite-users maillist involved just two SQL commands: SELECT InvalidateLayerStatistics(); (*)
SELECT UpdateLayerStatistics();